# What is the missing item in this symbolic or numerical series/set?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, symbols

Determine the missing item.

### I I I I V V V V XV XV XV XV XVI XVI XVIII XVIII XVIII XVIII XIX XIX XX XX XX XX ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go with:

> L

Since the sequence seems to be

> 1. Non-decreasing numerically as Roman numerals; and
>
>  2. Heading toward being palindromic in the number of strokes used
>
> ```
>  I I I I V V V V XV XV XV XV XVI XVI XVIII XVIII XVIII XVIII XIX XIX XX XX XX XX L L L L C C C C
>  1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2  4  4  4  4   5   5     7     7     7     7   5   5  4  4  4  4 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1
> ```